# How to stop generating mutiple time header columns in single file, In bindy component?

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

Hello I am working on a CSV file using camel bindy component where I split data into 1000 line of chunks and its generating header columns with each chunks, I need it should generate only one time with single file.
MyRoute:

```
final DataFormat inputCSV = new BindyCsvDataFormat(InputCSV.class);
final DataFormat outputCSV = new BindyCsvDataFormat(OutputCSV.class);

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:inbox/inputFile?fileName=inputProducts.csv&noop=true")
        .split().tokenize("\\n", 1000)
        .unmarshal(inputCSV)
        .bean(Processor.class, "processCSV")
        .marshal(outputCSV)
        .to("file:inbox/outputFile?fileExist=append&fileName=outputProduct.csv");
}
```

And my OutputCSV.java pojo

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",",generateHeaderColumns=true)
public class OutputCSV implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@DataField(pos = 1, required = true)
private String product_id;

@DataField(pos = 2, required = true)
private String product_name;

//Getter and setter
}
```

My question is how do I make this code so it will generate header once for single file ?

Answer (score 2):

You get a header per row because you process every single line and append to the file. In such a scenario you would have to set the `generateHeaderColumns` to `false` after the first line because only the file knows if the current row is the first one or not.

Either

1. You **collect** (aggregate) the whole data for a file before you marshal it (see below)
2. OR you add the **header "manually"** at the beginning of the file and set `generateHeaderColumns` to `false`
3. OR you **don't split** the file at all to get a List of objects from the `unmarshal` (see below)

For #1 you would have to implement an `AggregationStrategy` that collects all objects in a List. See [here](https://www.sourceallies.com/2014/01/how-to-implement-the-splitter-and-aggregator-patterns-with-apache-camel/) and look for `ArrayListAggregationStrategy.java` for an example.

For #3 the result of the `unmarshal` is a List of Maps where each Map contains the model objects from 1 CSV row (in your case it should be only 1 object per Map). Then your bean can iterate over the List (instead of working on one row), extract the model objects and collect them in a List to marshal them again. See the [Camel Bindy docs](http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html) under the section `Unmarshaling` for more details.

Comment: I did aggregation but I am doing wrong please can you show me how I use aggregate in DSL to collect all chunks and marshal together.

Comment: I have extended my answer with a third variation and some more details